# 'externalptr' error in R when creating a loop to scrape web data from multiple URLS

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, purrr

I want to scrape web data and put it in one data frame `enter code here`from multiple URLS that change only by numbers

[ERROR IN R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkvgs.png)

URL Example : https://necta.go.tz/results/2015/csee/results/p0101.htm

The only thing that changes on the URL is the "p0101" becoming "p0102","p0103" etc.

I have used the code below in R but I am very stuck.

R-CODE .. See Below

```
dflist <- map(.x = 0101:1000, .f = function(x) {
  Sys.sleep(5)
  url <- paste0("https://necta.go.tz/results/2015/csee/results/p",x,".htm")
   read_html(url) %>%
    html_nodes('.excerpt') %>%
    htmlTreeParse(url,useInternalNodes = TRUE) 
    getNodeSet(ExtractHTML1,"//tr//font")
    html_text() %>%
    as.data.frame()
}) %>% do.call(rbind, .)
```

Comment: `0101` is `101`, not `"0101"`. `sprintf` is handy for padding with 0s, though the notation is pretty confusing.

Comment: ...and if you're going to do `map(...) %>% do.call(rbind, .)`, just use `map_dfr` instead

Comment: ...and don't mix and match {rvest} and {XML}, which seems to be the immediate cause of the error. They can do the same things, but they're not interoperable, because they each store the data differently internally.

Comment: Can you please advise on what I can change on that cots for it to work?

Comment: I'd recommend switching to all {rvest}, so drop `htmlTreeParse` and `getNodeSet`.